# Windows 10 constant ping spike

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ping

I recently bought a new laptop (about a week ago) but I am constantly getting strange ping spikes that never stop. Tried restarting my laptop, with no avail.

Before I begin describing my issue let me paste the output of the command `ping`

```
ping -n 20 192.168.8.1 (my router's ip, approximately same result with 8.8.8.8 or any other ip or website)

Pinging 192.168.8.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=2453ms TTL=64 <- here 
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=2904ms TTL=64 <- again
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.8.1: bytes=32 time=2900ms TTL=64 <- good end :/

Ping statistics for 192.168.8.1:
    Packets: Sent = 20, Received = 20, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2904ms, Average = 419ms
```

With 20 total pings, this command outputs **at least** two ping spikes ranging from `2000ms` to `3000ms`, **nearly always**. I'm pretty sure this problem is related to my laptop (not my router) since I tried running this command in another *windows 10* computer, and also an *android* device (with termux) all connected to the same router, with a resulting ping **never** hitting more than `50ms`. I also tried to connect to another router but got the exact same result.

Given all these statements, I can conclude that the problem is from my laptop hardware (network adapter card) / software (network adapter driver *(there are no suggested updates)* / some faulty configuration in my internet settings / ...).

So, how can I further investigate in my issue, find the cause of it and finally fix it. Thanks for devoting your time to helping me <3 ❤

---

### My wifi model:

[image: .]

Comment: Looks like something fishy indeed. However ping times per se aren't really important, as ping does _not_ test network performance in any manner. The _only_ thing it does is verify that the target's actually up. In networking point of view ping is mgmt traffic, which always has the lowest priority. The target responds when it has time, and the sender processes the response when it has time - they _must_ process everything else before ping. What's important is are you experiencing some kind of issues for example when you're browsing the web?

Comment: To really measure the actual network throughput performance you need a different tool. Industry standard is iperf, you can download iperf3 client from [here](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php) (pick v. 3.1.3). Then you can use it to test the performance against one of [these](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php) public iperf servers. The basic command is `iperf -c <servername> -i 1`, but many of the servers work on specific ports. In that case command's `iperf -c <servername> -i 1 -p <portnr>`.  Servers are often busy, so you might need to try different ports or different servers.

Comment: Is .8 your local subnet?   Maybe get Wireshark (I use Comm View) to see what the packets re.

Comment: it doesn't present a big problem when browsing but sometimes it  becomes super annoying when playing some online games. thats the main reason that led me to check my ping

Comment: @Peregrino69 ok I will try this command and respond as soon as I can

Comment: The basic runtime of iperf3 is 10sec, but you can adjust it. For example to run a 60sec test you'll add `-t 60` at the end of the command. Please don't put test results in a comment, edit your question instead. If you're experiencing probs with online games, I'd expect to see similar jumps on iperf testing as well.

Comment: Hmm seems the spikes got fixed. I litterally did not do anyting. I'm really in a loss now. Will this problem occur again

Comment: I think you just confirmed my suspicion... answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short example you put in shows that these ping spikes occur with a steady rate, every 8 seconds. An app like [Wi-Fi Analyzer from Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/wifi-analyzer/9nblggh33n0n) is likely to show a drastic signal drop at the same time you see a ping spike.

That kind of signal drops at steady intervals are common for certain types of non-Wi-Fi interference. Unfortunately common Wi-Fi analyzer tools can't identify this kind of interference, it's only detectable with an expensive spectrum analyzer. There's a myriad of possible sources like radio controlled doors, alarm systems, some lighting installations... From what I've seen this kind of interference tends to happen on the lower end of the spectrum.

Check your router's Wi-Fi radio settings and change it to run on a different channel. Non-Wi-Fi interference is usually very narrow band, so it normally only affects one channel.

The current setting is most likely auto. If the settings have a channel exclusion list, you can also leave it on auto and just add the current channel to the exclusion list. This prevents the radio from ever using that channel at all.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Indeed, it was actually because of an app called "Feem" that keeps constantly checking for those connected to the network. As soon as I kill it the problem gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue across 3 different PCs at work and was only able to do a workaround as these are for staff working from home. These users run a phone client through the computer and whenever there is a ping spike (no timeouts), the phone line goes quiet so it cuts out (not a delay).

The workaround was to use a different network adapter so either using the LAN network adapter or use a 4G mobile broadband USB. This also has its own network adapter.

I leaning towards some Windows update causing the issue.

So still trying to pinpoint what's causing the wifi adapter connection to get ping spikes. BTW all 3 PCs are using same wifi usb on 3 different routers.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. The advice might help your users as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my laptop, tried all the solutions, even changed my wifi adapter and still spikes were showing each 10 seconds. Finally the following solution worked for me, hope it works for you as well:

You need to reset and enable WWAN and WLAN services, these services are essential to run the wireless and wired connection properly. Follow the steps below:

1. Open Services (Press Windows key + R then type in services.msc then click OK)
2. Look for WLAN Autoconfig and WWAN Autoconfig> Right Click Properties and set it to automatic (If it's already set to automatic, right click then click stop then start it again)
3. Restart PC and check

Cheers!

Peyman